# How about destroying a black hole?

Tags: black-holes

Can we destroy a [black hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole)? I know it is pretty powerful and hardcore stuff but there should be a way even theoretically as we know know nothing is perfect in this universe as it exist due to imperfection. Then how could a black hole be so perfect, so near to god power?

Comment: What do you mean by "perfect"?

Comment: I disagree this project. Many worlds might be destabilized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accepted science on black holes say that nothing can escape a black hole, not even light. But there are some theories that hawking radiation on the boarder of the event horizon, is made by virtual antimatter matter particle pairs, where either matter or antimatter is swallowed by the black hole, while matter or antimatter escape the black hole as hawking radiation. This causes the black hole to loose energy and mass and grow smaller. The black hole still has infinite gravity in the middle, but it's gravity well effect grow smaller. This is the most accepted current theory, but is just theory and we can't be sure if it is the truth, personally I doubt it.

So you wan't to blow up a black hole? Well, you must destabilize it in some way and we might be the black hole parallel to a super nova, and if all the mass is converted to energy in a short time it might be something like a doomsday device for entire galaxies. Maybe violent vibration of the gravity well might work? Black hole head to head collision? Putting a big antimatter bomb into the black hole? Sending a white hole into the black hole? But to blow up a black hole sounds like urge of a six year old and not God. God is rather sitting in the black hole in the center of galaxies enjoying creation and laughing at our silly questions.

Comment: As I know, the Hawking radiation is from photons and not from particle-antiparticle pairs.

Comment: After 4 years and much more knowledge on the subject , my childish dream to destroy a black hole got destroyed by black hole.

Answer (score 1):

Don't feed it, and wait for long enough, it'll evaporate. Your linked Wikipedia article has [more info about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole#Evaporation).

I'm afraid it's the only way.

Comment: No that should not be an answer we can't just wait and watch for our enemy in a war to evaporate

Comment: @Soonts is right, though. And what do you mean by "enemy"?